# Accessing a resource by its path rather than its byte content - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm writing a function which performs some operations from a DOCX file (building a custom TOC from it).

I'm a beginner in **unit testing**, and as far as I understand, it should be designed to check functionality **independently**.

I added a DOCX file as a **resource** in VS and configured it to be **copied** in the output directory.

The resource file is named `testDOCXFile` and can be accessed this way as an array of `Bytes`:

```
Dim content As My.Resources.testDOCXFile
```

The problem: the **function** I want to check **requires** a **String** describing the **path to a given file**.

Is there a "good-practice-compliant" way to **get a path** to this **resource**, **without** using **string constants** as shown below:

```
' Don't Repeat Yourself!
Dim contentPath = _
    IO.Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
                    "Resources", "testFile.docx")
```

Comment: if you want to access the file by its filename directly then there's no point adding it as a Resource. Just tell VS to include the file in the build output, and then use code to access it by its name.

Comment: So you simply don't have any real use for a resource.  Technically you can use Path.GetTempFileName() to generate the file dynamically, but it is pretty weak sauce for simply adding the file to the project.

Comment: @ADyson, so what I called a not DRY compliant call is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: @Amessihel you don't need to use string literals (note you are not using a _constant_, that's something else) in your call necessarily. The filename could be stored in config, or in a database, or wherever is appropriate in the context of the application.

Comment: @ADyson, yes literals sorry. What storage type will you suggest for a **unit test** project? I'm looking for something more "embedded" into the project.

Comment: well presumably your project has an app.config? That would be a reasonable place to store a (potentially) configurable value such as a target filename. Just as you might do so in any other type of project/app.

Comment: @ADyson, yes a test project can indeed have an `app.config`. Sounds to be the right choice. Thank you.